# How to create a MONGODB data source in weblogic

Tags: mongodb, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am new to weblogic and i am trying to setup a new data source to connect to mongodb in weblogic.

```
Driver.className: jdbc:mongodb:Server=10.10.10.1;Port=27017;Database=test;
URL:jdbc:mongodb
```

I am not sure where to add the mongodb jar so that weblogc can find the jar.
my weblogic installation path is:`C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1`

[image]

Can anybody suggest how to connect to mongodb succesfully???

Answer (score 2):

Add the jar in the /lib folder in your domain folder.

Answer (score 2):

In order to deploy a shared library in weblogic you need to follow the next steps: from the Weblogic console select *Deployments* and then on the right panel click *Install* button, then click the "**upload your file(s)**" link and select the jar you want to install click *next* and select the deploy/install as a library option. Make sure after you will see the jar uploaded in the Deplyoments, will be in State **active** Health **OK**, if is not then click checkbox next to the **jar** and click button *Start* and then select *Serving all Requests*

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated of
[connect mongodb atlas to weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587039/connect-mongodb-atlas-to-weblogic/76907049#76907049)

In short, WLS12c/WLS14c support JDBC 4.0 specification, but as MongoDB is a NoSQL DB, you should use the MongoDB Java Driver instead.

References:

WLS support note: Are There Steps Using WLS Console to Configure Access to the Mongo Database (DB) Via Datasources (Doc ID 2636701.1)

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/administration/connection-pool-overview/