# connect mongodb atlas to weblogic

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, weblogic, datasource

Need to create a datasource in weblogic, with the following from mongodb

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@pl-1-eastus2-azure.u0tys.mongodb.net:1024,pl-1-eastus2-azure.u0tys.mongodb.net:1025,pl-1-eastus2-azure.u0tys.mongodb.net:1026/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-m3p2tp-shard-0
```

I don't know where to place the driver and how to place the fields correctly

Answer (score 0):

WLS12c doesn't support datasources for MongoDB.

Instead, your web app should use the connection pool provided by the MongoDB driver:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/administration/connection-pool-overview/